# permission denied with open()

Tags: c, linux, file-io

The issue arises with fopen(), stating that permission is denied. I have tried to input all the modes however this was unsuccessful. Same when adding all the writing modes. I am attempting to open a file to with which i can write. Thanks to anyone who helps

```
if(filename != NULL && redirectArrow == true){

    mode_t modes = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;
        int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT , S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH); //opening file in write only, and creating file if it does not exist 

if(fd == -1){
    perror("Failed to create and open the file\n");
    exit(3);
}
```

Comment: do you have the right to create a file in the directory corresponding  the path of *filename* ? Is the file already exist and you do not have the right on it ? Is the directory corresponding  the path of *filename* already exist ?

Comment: What *is* the file you try to open? *Where* (on your disk) do you try to create this file? Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. Fortunately i was able to resolve the issue. Not sure why it was not working before, but i added groups and user read and write permissions and it worked as inteded